# Web Crawler in Grails to calculate page depth

Tags: parsing, grails, web-crawler

I am making a crawler application. I wish to crawl websites and find the depth of the webpages retrieved. I read about different crawling and parsing tools but to no avail. None of them seem to provide support to calculate the depth. I am also unsure about which crawler tool to use which can get closest to desired functionality. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am working on something similar. You could try crawler4j for crawling purpose . The depth part even I have been researching about.

Comment: I know about JSoup being the best available parser for Grails app, but not sure if even that gives the capability to calculate depth.

Comment: I tried two different parser in Java: JSoup and Jaunt. Both solutions are great but I prefer JSoup. But at the end, it is just a parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important thing is probably the mapping of your Domain (and not the parser).

Because, if you are using a tree ([More information on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28graph_theory%29)), it is easy to calculate the depth (the min depth) of your URL.

Hope this helps.