# Crawler4j calculate depth of a page

Tags: grails, groovy, depth, crawler4j

I am developing a web crawler using groovy & grails and mongodb Is there any way to calculate depth of a page using crawler4j? I know I can limit upto what depth I want to crawl but haven't come across anything that suggests how to calculate depth of the page. Thanks.

Comment: This will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24416214/web-crawler-in-grails-to-calculate-page-depth.

Answer (score 2):

Crawler4j calculates depth of page.

```
webUrl.getDepth();
```